# Perform floating point arithmetic in shell script variable definitions

Tags: bash, shell-script, bc

I understand `bash` and some other interpreters only perform arithmetic for integers.  In the following `for` loop, how can I accomplish this?  I've read that `bc` can be used but am not sure how to use `bc` in this situation.

```
total=0
for number in `cat /path/to/file`; do
        total=$(($total+$number))
done
average=$(($total/10))
echo Average is $average
```

file:

```
1.143362
1.193994
1.210489
1.210540
1.227611
1.243496
1.260872
1.276752
1.294121
1.427371
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense to calculate the average in every round of the loop if only the last result is used, does it?

Comment: `ksh` (ksh93) and `zsh` do do floating point arithmetics.

Comment: Same question on [SO]: [Floating-point arithmetic in UNIX shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14222250/2157640)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may not want to use `bc` for this.  Perhaps `awk` would work better:

```
awk '{sum+=$1};END{print sum/NR}' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 8):

As tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), here is a `bash` 4.0 alternative to [choroba](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13792/choroba)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76068), to avoid `wc` and `sed`:

```
bash-4.2$ mapfile -t a < file

bash-4.2$ (IFS='+'; echo "(${a[*]})/${#a[@]}") | bc -l
1.24886080000000000000
```

Comment: If it's about bash I think this is much nicer: `shopt -s extglob; value=...; value="${value%%*(0)}"; if [ -z "${value##*.}" ]; then value="${value}0"; fi; echo "$value"`. But for next time: I note your "Organizer" badge... 8-)

Answer (score 3):

I usually use `bc` for floating point arithmetics:

```
file=1.txt
echo '('$(<$file)')/'$(wc -l < $file) | sed 's/ /+/g' | bc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
term=0
file=input
for number in `cat "$file"`; do
        term="${term}+${number}"
done
total="$(echo "$term" | bc -l)"
average="$(echo "${total}/10" | bc -l)"
average="$(echo "$average" | sed -e 's/^\(.*\..*[^0]\)0*/\1/' -e p)"
echo "Total: ${total}"
echo "Average: ${average}"
```

Comment: @JohnB Then you should accept it as answer (i.e. click on the green check mark below the voting for my answer).

Comment: :) I guess it's not hard to tell I'm new to the site...and scripting.

Comment: For some reason, using `sed` in this solution caused $average to echo twice.  I substituted with `cut -c-9` and it fixed it. Have no clue why.

Comment: @JohnB You should really try the `awk` alternative. Don't use `bash` for these kind of tasks!